# JQuery is checked length not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if any two check boxes are checked and enable other check-boxes. Please note no access to HTML. Any tips might help as this might be an easy fix.

code below:

```
 //this disables checkboxes on load
 for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        $("#xQ7v3_" +i).prop("disabled", true );
        $("#xQ7v4_" +i).prop("disabled", true );

    }
     //if any two ids are checked want to enable the ones that are disabled on load but does not work basically does nothing, no console errors
     $('#xQ7v1_1, #xQ7v2_1, #xQ7v1_2, #xQ7v2_2, #xQ7v1_3, #xQ7v2_3, #xQ7v1_4, #xQ7v2_4').change(function() {
        for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        if ($('#xQ7v1_1, #xQ7v2_1, #xQ7v1_2, #xQ7v2_2, #xQ7v1_3, #xQ7v2_3, #xQ7v1_4, #xQ7v2_4').is(':checked').length > 1 ) {

            $("#xQ7v3_" +i).prop("disabled", false );
            $("#xQ7v4_" +i).prop("disabled", false );

        } else{

            $("#xQ7v3_" +i).prop("disabled", true );
            $("#xQ7v4_" +i).prop("disabled", true );


        }

    });
```

Comment: that will not work. is(":checked") returns a Boolean and you are thing to get a length off it

Comment: what should i do instead?

Comment: for each of the controls add a class, say "ischecked" then you can simply do   $(".islchecked:checked").length

Comment: what about `$(:checked)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery's [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns a boolean after ...

> Checking the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return **true** if **at least one** of these elements matches the given arguments.

---

This means that you need to change your jquery selector from

```
$('#xQ7v1_1, #xQ7v2_1, #xQ7v1_2, #xQ7v2_2, #xQ7v1_3, #xQ7v2_3, #xQ7v1_4, #xQ7v2_4').is(':checked').length
```

to...

```
$('#xQ7v1_1:checked, #xQ7v2_1:checked, #xQ7v1_2:checked, #xQ7v2_2:checked, #xQ7v1_3:checked, #xQ7v2_3:checked, #xQ7v1_4:checked, #xQ7v2_4:checked').length
```

---

An example:

```js
$("input").change(() => {
  console.log($('#check1:checked, #check2:checked').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id=check1 type="checkbox" id="1" name="1">
<label for="1">Box 1</label>

<input id="check2" type="checkbox" id="2" name="2">
<label for="1">Box 2</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that all the Ids start with `xQ7v` then why not simplify to:
`$("input[id^='xQ7v']:checked").length`